# Как сменить цвет для элемента типа chtype из curses

Tags: c++, c, curses

При создании элемента типа `chtype` задаю цвет:

```
chtype a = ' ' | COLOR_PAIR(COLOR);
```

Но, что делать, если мне нужно поменять цвет? Для этого я использую приведение типов, вроде:

```
a = static_cast<char>(a) | COLOR_PAIR(NEW_COLOR);
```

Но выглядит достаточно громоздко. Есть ли способ получше?

Comment: `chtype` — это `wchar_t`. `COLOR_PAIR` возвращает `int`. Думаю, каст тут вообще не нужен. Так что можно так: `a |= COLOR_PAIR(NEW_COLOR)`.

Comment: @eanmos, что-то путаешь... в `chtype` — это char с атрибутами... аналог `wchar_t` из ncursesw — это структура `cchar_t`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, хм… Да, вроде, не путаю: `typedef wchar_t chtype;`. Смотрел [здесь](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libcurses/curses.h?rev=1.86&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup).

Comment: @eanmos, забавно и странно... определение несколько сконфуживает... не вижу в этом особой логики... в любом случае [работают](https://github.com/sabotage-linux/netbsd-curses/blob/ab92743125ff37b8af268ac362b604ed45bf6e29/libcurses/addchnstr.c#L157) они с ним явно не как с нормальным wchar'ом... в ncurses — это либо `unsigned`, либо `uint32_t` на современных системах... в `pdcurses` примерно также, но там под символ отводятся нижние два байта в ucs-2, а `cchar_t` тождественен `ctype`'у

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для доступа к отдельным частям `chtype` у ncurses есть свои битовые маски: `A_ATTRIBUTES`, `A_CHARTEXT`, `A_COLOR` (см. [`man curs_inch`](http://opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=curs_inch&category=3&russian=3)).

Таким образом сброс цвета будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
a = (a & ~A_COLOR) | COLOR_PAIR(NEW_COLOR);
```

Можно тоже самое записать в две строчки:

```
a &= ~A_COLOR;
a |= COLOR_PAIR(NEW_COLOR);
```

Исходное выражение сбрасывает одновременно и цвет, и атрибуты (мигание, яркость, подчёркивание итп), если это действительно желаемый результата, то можно пользоваться `A_CHARTEXT`:

```
a = (a & A_CHARTEXT) | COLOR_PAIR(NEW_COLOR);
```

Замечания:

- `A_ATTRIBUTES` также включает в себя цвет.
- Для работы с широкими символами есть аналогичные маски `WA_ATTRIBUTES`, `WA_CHARTEXT` и `WA_COLOR`. В реализации ncurses они тождественны обычным.